# shuffle in the model.fit of keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

In the `model.fit` of `keras`, there is a `shuffle` parameter,

```
shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not  None.
```

Assume the training set is a list with `50000` elements, so the whole list will be randomly permuted before each epoch? Of if the batch size is `250`, only the elements belonging to each batch get permuted? What should be the correct understanding?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It will [shuffle your entire dataset (`x`, `y` and `sample_weight` together) first](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L169-L172) and then [make batches](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L174-L187) according to the `batch_size` argument you passed to `fit`.

### Edit

As @yuk pointed out in the comment, the code has been changed significantly since 2018. The documentation for the `shuffle` parameter now seems more clear on its own. You can choose to shuffle the entire training data or just shuffle the batch:

```
        shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data
            before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is ignored
            when `x` is a generator. 'batch' is a special option for dealing
            with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized
            chunks. Has no effect when `steps_per_epoch` is not `None`.
```

Comment: The links do not exist anymore. :(

Comment: [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: I have made lots and lots of trainning trying to use that "shuffle" embedded, but seems not work for me!! Even verifying all this conditions!! Because I cannot verify if is really doing shuffle, I´m not using that anymore!! There is other ways to do the same!! If you pass throught the same, and find a solution, let me know!!! Thanxxxxxxxxx