# How does model.fit process images?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have a *training dataset* with images that looks like this:

```
x=[image1,image2...imageN]
```

and an output dataset that looks like this:

```
y=[output1,output2...]
```

I don't understand how does the `model.fit` works in regards to processing the images. Meaning, if I choose `shuffle=False` will the model take the first image first and go through the whole feedforward, backprop, etc. and compare it to `output1`, and then the second image, and so on?
Or does the model randomly select images from my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `shuffle = True` the generator will shuffle the dataset before each epoch. It will then go through the shuffled dataset one batch at a time, if it reaches then end before the next epoch it will go back to the start.

If you specify `shuffle = False` it will go through the dataset in the same order every epoch.

Comment: Please spend some time to learn how to properly format in-line code (done it for you this time)

Comment: Oh, my apologies! Thank you very much for the help. So just to make it clear, if I set shuffle=false the model will go through the dataset in similar order every epoch. However, we don't know if it takes the first element in the training dataset list, then the second, and so on, or it randomly chooses elements the first time, and follows the same order afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it takes them in order. Once you initialise `flow_from_directory` it will find all the valid files in the directory tree and sort them. If you set `shuffle = False` every epoch it will go through this sorted list in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a similar question is asked here.
[shuffle in the model.fit of keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184144/shuffle-in-the-model-fit-of-keras)

As far as I know, your thought process is correct up to a certain extent. The model takes a random image from the dataset and the associated output for that index and then trains on it. Quite similar to using a random number to select an image from the batch, training it comparing with the output and then marking it as trained to avoid retraining on the same example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So what is the point of shuffling if the model takes a random image anyway? Are you sure that what you described is not the case where shuffle=True?